# OOP: improperly applied inheritance?

Tags: java, oop

I believe that I'm applying inheritance improperly.

Here my interface `ResourceProvider`:

```java
public interface ResourceProvider {

    ResourceLocation generatePushResourceLocation(DocumentId documentId);

    ResourceLocation generatePullResourceLocation(DocumentId documentId);

}
```

I'm trying to model a single method signatures that all `ResourceProvider` have to follow.

Subclasses: `S3ResourceProvider`, `BlobResourceProvider`, `URLResourceProvider`...

Initially, it seems like they all may exhibit the same behavior, but for instance, the `S3ResourceProvider` requires a `bucket` and a `key`, whereas the `URLResourceProvider` only needs a URL..."

The use case is that my service must be able to handle a request for the creation of a resource. What I wanted to achieve was to have a uniform access point to any type of `ResourceProvider`, but I find myself at the same time that they all have different parameters.

Any ideas about how to make a good inheritance / composition strategy?

Comment: What you have done is interface design. There is nothing here that would facilitate inheritance yet. For inheritance you need a concrete class. You might want to start by implementing two of the providers and then if you can't find a proper way forward, post the code you have created and ask for help on the specific issues.

Comment: Seems like you need factory pattern - `ResourceProviderFactory`. Then you have concrete factories - `S3ResourceProviderFactory` -> `new S3ResourceProvider(bucket, key)`, `URLResourceProviderFactory` -> `new URLResourceProvider(url)` and so on.

Comment: You need three different classes `S3ResourceProvider`, `URLResourceProvider`, and `BlobResourceProvider`, these will implement the `ResourceProvider` interface. What is the use of one class requiring a `bucket` and `key` and the other classes requiring something different? To access the underlying connection? This would be at a different layer than the actual implementation (inheritance) of your interface. It seems that each implementation would then need a different way of accessing its storage or db etc, but that seems unrelated to the interface and inheritance.

Comment: If you want all implementations to be able to use the same interface (accepting only `documentId`), you will need to provide the rest of the details (e.g., `bucket`) in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `URI` instead of a `ResourceLocation` in your interface. For a URL it would be something like "https://service/docs/some.doc", for S3 something like "S3://mybucket/some.doc", etc.

Your classes (`URLResourceProvider`, `S3ResourceProvider` etc.) will then implement this interface, accepting in specific constructors the necessary objects to do their work.